# How to get input array index value in jquery as variable

Tags: jquery

My html form is designed as following structure

```
<ul>
    <li><input type='checkbox' value='car' name='menu[]' value='vehicle'>Sports
        <ul>
            <li><input type='checkbox' name='submenu[vehicle][car]'>Car</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I need to access index of two-dimensional array in jquery. First index would be it's parent `li`'s input value, and this value is stored in jquery variable as below(in snippet), How can access second index of array ? I need in jquery like this

```
var menu = vehicle
var submenu = car
```

Following example would help to make question clear.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('change', 'input[name="menu[]"]', function() {
    var nav = [];
    $("input[name='menu[]']:checked").each(function() {
      nav.push(this.value);
    });
    alert(nav);

// What can I --

    var subnav = [];
    $("input[name='submenu[][]']:checked").each(function() {
      subnav.push(this.value);
    });

    alert(subnav);

  });

// -- do here to get index not value ?

  $('[name="submenu[][]"]').parent().each(function() {
    if ($(this).children("ul").length) {
      $(this).parents('[name="menu[]"]').click(false);
    }
  })
  $('li:has(> ul)').find('[name="menu[]"]').click(false);
  $('[name="menu[]"] + ul input').click(function() {
    $(this).closest("ul").prev("input").prop("checked", ($(this).closest("ul").find("input:checked").length > 0));
  });

});
```

```css
ul li {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <ul>
    <li><input type="checkbox" value='sport' name='menu[]'>Sports</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" value='vehicle' name='menu[]'>Vehicle
      <ul>
        <li><input type='checkbox' value='car' name='submenu[vehicle][car]' value='car'>Car</li>
        <li><input type='checkbox' value='car' name='submenu[vehicle][bike]' value='car'>Bike</li>
      </ul>

    </li>

  </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You might have a problem here `$("input[name='submenu[][]']:checked")` since you have nothing named `submenu[][]`

Comment: Can you please first of all describe what you are trying to _achieve_ here? Not sure if _“I need to access index of multidimensional array in jquery”_ is really what you need as of now.

Comment: @CBroe, you can see there is no value with `submenu[][]` in html form, but second index of this two dimensional array would be filled dynamically, such as it would be `submenu[1][2]`, `submenu[1][3]`, `submenu[1][4]`,`submenu[1][5]` I want to achieve the second index and stored in variable - such as, 2,3,4,5..

Comment: Not what I meant; please describe what kind of _functionality_ you are trying to implement here.